# Remove leading and trailing whitespace directories

Tags: bash, unix, whitespace

The problem is that Mac OS X lets folders get names like `"    Foo  Bar   /"`.

This is what I could fix on my own and it works for most of the problems.

```
for d in */ ; do
    echo "$d" | xargs
done
```

Result: `"Foo Bar /"`.

The only problem it leaves that last space between the directory name and the slash.

Can someone help get rid of that last space?

Comment: Thanks for the format cleanup fedorqui. Should have cleaned it up before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for a bash-only approach:

```
dir="some dir /"
fixed=${dir/ \///}
echo $fixed
some dir/
```

Bash string manipulation:

**SUBSTRING REMOVAL BEGINNING OF STRING**:

```
${string#substring}         - remove shortest substring match from beginning

${string##substring}        - remove longest substring match from beginning
```

**SUBSTRING REMOVAL END OF STRING**:

```
${string%substring}         - remove shortest matching substring from tail 

${string%%substring}        - remove longest matching substring from tail
```

**SUBSTRING REPLACEMENT**:

```
${string/substring/replacement}      - replace first match of substring

${string//substring/greplacement}    - replace all matches of substring

${string/#substring/replacement}     - replace substring at front of string

${string/%substring/replacement}     - replace substring at tail of string
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using sed like this:

```
name="    Foo  Bar   /"
echo "$name" | sed 's/^\s*\(.*\)\s*$/\1/g' | tr -s ' '
```

The sed expression removes all spaces before and after your name, while tr squeezes them to a maximum of one.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that Mac OS X lets folders get names like "    Foo  Bar   /"

This is a Unix/BASH issue too. All characters *except* `NUL` and forward slash are valid characters in file names. This includes control characters like *backspace* and UTF8 characters.

You can use `${WORD%%filter}` and `${WORD##filter}` to help remove the extra spaces on the front and end of files. You might also want to substitute white space with an *underscore* character. Unix shell scripts usually work better if file names don't contain white space:

```
for file in *
do
   new_file=$(tr -s " "<<<"$file")
   mv "$file" "$new_file"
done
```

The `tr -s " "` uses the `tr` command to *squeeze* spaces out of the file name. This also squeezes beginning and ending spaces on Mac OS X too. This doesn't remove tab characters or NLs (although they could be added to the string.

The `for file in *` does assign the file names correctly to `$file`. The `<<<` is a Bashism to allow you to redirect a string as STDIN. This is good because `tr` only works with STDIN. The `$(...)` tells Bash to take the output of that command and to interpolate it into the command line.

This is a fairly simply script and may choke on other file names. I suggest you try it like this:

```
for file in *
do
   new_file=$(tr -s " "<<<"$file")
   echo "mv '$file' '$new_file' >> output.txt
done
```

Then, you can examine `output.txt` to verify that the `mv` command will work. Once you've verifies `output.txt`, you can use it as a bash script:

```
$ bash output.txt
```

That will then run the `mv` commands you've saved in output.txt.